# Comment transpose/traduit-on la locution proverbiale « variety is the spice of life » ? How do you adapt/translate "variety is the spice of life"?

Tags: traduction, anglais, expressions-idiomatiques, proverbes

En langue anglaise on a la locution proverbiale « variety is the spice of life » (en ligne : [tFD](https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/variety+is+the+spice+of+life), [M-W](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/variety%20is%20the%20spice%20of%20life), [Cambridge](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/variety-is-the-spice-of-life), [Collins](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/variety-is-the-spice-of-life), [M-Learners](https://learnersdictionary.com/definition/spice)), du poète William Cowper : « Variety's the very spice of life, That gives it all its flavour » ; on signale qu'Euripide avait une expression de même sens ([Oxford Reference online](https://www.oxfordreference.com/view/10.1093/oi/authority.20110803115237787), *The Oxford Dictionary of Phrase and Fable*).

---

Connaît-on une transposition ou une traduction ; pourquoi le mot à mot « la variété est l'épice de la vie » est-il adéquat ou non ?

---

There is this proverbial saying in English "variety is the spice of life" (online: [tFD](https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/variety+is+the+spice+of+life), [M-W](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/variety%20is%20the%20spice%20of%20life), [Cambridge](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/variety-is-the-spice-of-life), [Collins](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/variety-is-the-spice-of-life), [M-Learners](https://learnersdictionary.com/definition/spice)),  "originally as a quotation from the English poet William Cowper (1731–1800) in The Task (1785): ‘Variety's the very spice of life, That gives it all its flavour.’" and the Greek dramatist Euripides had something along those lines ([Oxford Reference online](https://www.oxfordreference.com/view/10.1093/oi/authority.20110803115237787), *The Oxford Dictionary of Phrase and Fable*).

---

Is there an equivalent or a known translation to this ; is "la variété est l'épice de la vie" good enough: why or why not?

Answer (score 3):

Une citation qui garde l'esprit mais un peu dans l'autre sens :

« L'ennui naquit un jour de l'uniformité. »*

Antoine Houdar de la Motte, Les Amis trop d'accord, Fables ([Wikipédia](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Antoine_Houdar_de_La_Motte#Post%C3%A9rit%C3%A9_litt%C3%A9raire))

> C'est un grand agrément que la diversité : 
> Nous sommes bien comme nous sommes.
> Donnez le même esprit aux hommes,
> Vous ôtez tout le sel de la société.
> L'ennui naquit un jour de l'uniformité.

Sans « le sel de la société, » sans épice, sans piment, ce n'est pas loin du sens du proverbe en anglais. Rien contre les traductions bien connues, mais il est intéressant de noter que les *Fables nouvelles* de La Motte, ça date de 1719.  Donc ce n'est pas une traduction de Cowler mais une autre manière d'exprimer cette idée.

*c.f. Balzac et l'université

Comment: *Spice* est bien rendu par « sel » dans ce sens ([TLF](https://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/sel)Af2) et « le sel de la vie » est la tournure la plus idiomatique pour rendre *the spice of life* mais la réponse est incomplète, pourquoi ne pas proposer « la diversité est le sel de la vie » ?  (« diversité » rend mieux ici le sens de *variety* que proposent certaines traductions mot à mot, mais pas [toutes](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22la+diversit%C3%A9+est+le+sel+de+la+vie%22&tbm=bks&ei=eUvlYP7MBsiYabz8vng&start=10&sa=N&ved=2ahUKEwi-7YKXrNDxAhVITBoKHTy-Dw8Q8tMDegQIARBB&biw=1860&bih=909&dpr=1)!

Answer (score 0):

La traduction de cette citation de William Cowper n'offre aucune difficulté ; on la trouve répétée assez souvent.

> ([L'internaute](https://www.linternaute.fr/citation/40461/la-variete-est-la-veritable-epice-de-la-vie-----william-cowper-brann/))
> La variété est la véritable épice de la vie - Qui lui donne toute sa saveur.

La voici de nouveau en version complète (mais avec une nuance)

> ([Pinterest](https://www.pinterest.fr/pin/507780926727943934/))
> La variété est la véritable épice de la vie qui lui donne toute sa saveur.

> ([Le Figaro](http://evene.lefigaro.fr/citation/variete-veritable-epice-vie-donne-toute-saveur-7711.php)) La traduction suivante est un peu plus fidèle en cela que la marque du commencement du second vers est préservée, mais la virgule, qui fait de la relative une proposition descriptive, manque.

> La variété est la véritable épice de la vie Qui lui donne toute sa saveur.

La voilà maintenant réduite à ses composantes minimales.

> ([Mur de célébrités](http://www.murdescelebrites.com/citations/lire/william-cowper/34576/))
> La variété est l'épice de la vie.

Le mot « variété » convient parce que son acception la plus générale est définie comme suit.

> (TLFi) **A.** − Caractère de ce qui est varié, qualité d'un ensemble dont les éléments sont différents. Synon. diversité.
> ♦ Extraordinaire, extrême, grande, immense, inépuisable, riche variété; jolie, magnifique, merveilleuse variété; manquer de variété; sans variété; d'une grande variété.
> ♦  Par les rues, par les places (...) par les quais coulait un fleuve d'êtres humains se dirigeant vers le Nil. La variété la plus étrange bariolait cette multitude.   (Gautier, Rom. momie, 1858, p. 205)
> ♦ Toute littérature est variété illimitée.  (Valéry, Regards sur monde act., 1931, p. 277)

L'ensemble est entièrement quelconque et peut être le plus vaste imaginable, comme par exemple l'ensemble des situations et états qu'offre la vie.

Ensuite, le mot « épice » se comprend très bien figurativement en français.

> ([TLFi](https://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/%C3%A9pice)) **B.** − Au fig. Ce qui ajoute du piquant à un sentiment, à une situation.
> ♦ Le désir. Présent, c'est bien en lui, il me semble, que j'aurais puisé, sans effort, le sens de notre rendez-vous de ce soir, l'épice, le danger qui lui faisait défaut.  (Colette, Naiss. jour,1928, p. 50)
> ♦ ... le plaisir et l'amour du mal ne sont parfaits que grâce au piquant de la contradiction intérieure et à la saveur du fruit défendu, comme pour ces filles galantes qui ont l'épice d'un prie-dieu. Blondel, L'Action,1893, p. 7.

Comment: Oui, chacun des mots peut avoir le sens voulu. Mais je ne suis pas sûr que la phrase soit compréhensible sans la partie « qui lui donne toute sa saveur » si on ne connaît pas l'original anglais. Et même avec ça, le sens de « variété » est très vague.